# How to remove # from the url in sencha web app

Tags: javascript, web, sencha-touch

I am working on a Sencha web application. I need to remove the `#` from the URL which comes after the `index.html`.

In every screen I navigate I see `...../index.html#Controller/view..` I need to get rid of this `#`.

I tried adding the code in each view's constructor, but didn't help...

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.indexOf('#') != -1) {
   url = url.substr(0, url.indexOf('#'));
}
window.location.assign(url);
```

I am using Sencha 1.1.1 version and Javascript. There is no external framework like phone gap used.

Comment: Beware, Sencha adds that anchor with some random data to prevent caching, so I hope you have a good reason for this.

Comment: So is this not possible ?

Comment: How do you navigate to other screens? Do you call `dispatch` method in your code?

Comment: @user2733130 Yes, it's possible, but you should have a good reason for this and understand the consequences.

Comment: yes i call dispatch for navigation... How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `historyUrl: false` for options that you pass to `dispatch` call. It looks from [source code](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/1.1.1/source/Dispatcher.html#Ext-util-Dispatcher-method-dispatch) for this method that this option should prevent adding action to history.